# Implementation of strdup() in C programming

Tags: c

I'm working on the implementation of `strdup()` in C, I'm new to C and I'm trying to build my own library. I'm using the actual `strdup()` from `string.h` to test mine and I run into a bus error when I test my source against a main program but none when I use the actual `strdup()`. Also I can't use any existing functions excluding `malloc()`.

Source code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *ft_strdup(char *src)
{

    char *str;
    int len;

    while (src[len])
        len++;
    str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(*str) * (len+1));
    while (*src)
        *str++ = *src++;
    *str = '\0';
    return (str);
}
```

Why do I keep getting a bus error?

Comment: You miss to initialize `len` with 0

Comment: *I'm new to C and I'm trying to build my own library* -- Generally not a good idea. I had been using C for many years before [I started my own standard library](http://pdclib.e43.eu/), and I'm still at it many years later. The `<string.h>` functions are quite easy, generally speaking, but you will rapidly run into problems (or implement the functions too naively, leaving you with a frustratingly broken project). Try something on the user side of the standard lib for your first steps.

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks, How do i return the pointer back to the beginning?

Comment: @user3121023 Nevermind, Thanks for everything ive cracked it.

Comment: strdup() is not part of the standard library, so there are situations (like porting code that depends on it to other systems), where you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: On allocation error `strdup()` is supposed to return `NULL` and set `errno` to `ENOMEM`, not crash with a segmentation fault (if you're on a platform with memory protection, if not, the function will do worse things).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try following fix:

1. Initialize `len` before increment it.
2. [Don't cast `malloc`'s return value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/436559), and don't use `sizeof(char)`, it's defined to be 1 in the standard, per cstd 6.5.3.4p4:

   > When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or
   >   signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.
3. Use a pointer to save the original `str` pointer

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *ft_strdup(char *src)
{
    char *str;
    char *p;
    int len = 0;

    while (src[len])
        len++;
    str = malloc(len + 1);
    p = str;
    while (*src)
        *p++ = *src++;
    *p = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain point 2? With regards to the casting of malloc and use of sizeof?

Comment: @afullstopdot Sure, I've updated the post for the reason of point 2.

Comment: I literally started using stackoverflow an hour ago, I didnt know i could do that. @machine_1. I will now.

Comment: Note that `*p++ = *src++` is equivalent to `*(p++) = *(src++)` because the postfix operator `++` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`.

Comment: fluter that wasthe answer that I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you must implement your own `strdup` function, at least rely on the rest of string.h for as much as you can. Many of these functions are optimized, and faster than you can write them yourself. For example, `strlen` is probably using SSE instructions, while your manual search for the null-terminator byte is not. It's also less code, which is always better. In short, I would suggest this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *ft_strdup(const char *s1)
{
  char *str;
  size_t size = strlen(s1) + 1;

  str = malloc(size);
  if (str) {
    memcpy(str, s1, size);
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to null-terminate the string. `str[len] = '\0'`. Please edit your post and correct this.

Comment: `char *ft_strdup(const char *str) { return strcpy(malloc(strlen(src)+1), str); }` ;-)

Comment: But of course the op's function, yours and mine have all a wrong semantic, in that the real `strdup()` returns `NULL` on allocation error, not a `segmentation fault`!

Comment: @Lundin: Actually, I should have just copied the null-terminator in the memcpy. A simple + 1 does the trick.

Comment: Enno thank you so much for your clean explanation!