# ERROR: A function Can't return char type in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm trying to make a ADT, but when I created a function that return char type, the program is not working. This is the ADT:

```
typedef struct{
int ID;
char Writer[100];
char Title[100];
long Year;
}Book;
```

the function is:

```
char GetTitle(Book B){
return B.Title;
}
```

I used this to get the return value of the function:

```
printf("%s",GetTitle(B));
```

How do I return Char type?

Comment: `B.Title` is an array of characters `char *` type.

Comment: `B.Title` has type `char[100]`. The compiler cannot convert that (even after automatic conversion to `char*`) to type `char`.

Comment: Try changing `char GetTitle(Book B);` to `char* GetTitle(Book *B);`.

Comment: What is the **error** that you get?

Comment: You should try to pass around pointers to your structures, rather than the structures themselves: `char GetTitle(Book *B);`.

Comment: when I run the program, the program is not responding

Comment: thanks guys, it worke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You return a char* instead

```
char* GetTitle(Book *B){
    return B->Title;
}
```

Note that this is just returning a pointer to the title of the book. So when the book is destroyed, the pointer becomes invalid. You can't return the whole title, as you can't return an array. If you want to make a copy of the string after you got the pointer (so it stays valid after destroying the book), use `strdup`:

```
Book* B = malloc(sizeof(Book));
// [...] initialize the book...
char *title = strdup(GetTitle(B));
free(B);
printf("%s",title);
free(title);
```

Edit: if `strdup` is not available, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37132824/10411602) for an implementation.

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped. :)

Comment: It works by mere chance. The structure B is not passed by reference, so technically `GetTitle(B)` is returning an address not yet valid. Don't do it, ever. Do `GetTitle(&B)` instead, changing the argument type of your function from `Book` to `Book*`.

Comment: Thank you, @Giovanni. I was so focused on that return type that I didn't notice this issue. I changed my answer.

Comment: Why are you doing `strdup`/`free`? Note also that `strdup` is not a standard function. And at the end you would also need to call `free(title);`.

Comment: Since OP tried to return a string, I wanted to make sure that he knows that returning a `char*` is NOT returning a string, merely a pointer to it. That's why I also posted how to make a copy of that string, incase he want to use the string independant of the actual `Book`.

Comment: There are no string in C. Strings are just pointers to the first `char` of a `char` array.

Comment: With `string` I meant the memory actually holding the string of characters as opposed to the pointer pointing to it. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Giovanni The C standard contradicts your claim and defines a string as "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely must read warnings passed by the compiler: for sure it is telling you can't return an address from the stack of a function. It works by mere chance, as that memory is not valid after the function returns. You must proceed using pointers and references. Try changing `char GetTitle(Book B);` to `char* GetTitle(Book *B);`, like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int ID;
    char Writer[100];
    char Title[100];
    long Year;
} Book;

char* GetTitle(Book *B) {
    return B->Title;
}

int main() {
    Book B;
    strcpy(B.Title, "Title");
    printf("%s\n", GetTitle(&B));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sure, but the `&` operator is used to accomplish the referencing.