# Function's pointer return keeps changing previous values in an array

Tags: c, pointers, scope, return-value, undefined-behavior

im trying to fill a 2d array with strings, problem is that i manage to fill the first index, however when i proceed to the next string it keeps changing the previous indexes. probably an issue with the pointer, this is the relevant code.

```
char* get_song_name(const char* song)
{
    strip(song);
    FILE* fp = fopen(song, "r");
    char str[9999];
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fgets(str,9999,fp);
        puts(str);
        strip(str);
        char* s = str;
        return s;
    }

` DIFFERENT FUNCTION:
for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
    {
        char *st = fgets(buff, 250, fp);
        st = create_path("c:\\Users\\Marian\\Desktop\\beatles", st);
        name[i] = get_song_name(st); //WORKS HOWEVER CHANGES PRVIOUS INDEXES VALUE TOO
    }`
```

Comment: The `get_song_name` opens the same file over and over again, every time reading one single line from the beginning and returning it. And what's worse, it returns a pointer to the local `str` array, a variable whose life-time will end when the function returns making the returned pointer invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dynamically allocate the string so its lifetime does not end then the functions exits.

Just replace

```
return s;
```

with

```
return strdup(s);
```

---

#### EDIT

As OP is not allowed to use `string.h` here one can find
an implementation of `strdup()` found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37132824/4989451

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *ft_strdup(char *src)
{
    char *str;
    char *p;
    int len = 0;

    while (src[len])
        len++;
    str = malloc(len + 1);
    p = str;
    while (*src)
        *p++ = *src++;
    *p = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

Comment: And if im not allowed to use <String.h>? i tried to do dynamic allocation but i couldn't quite make it work.

Comment: @noornapso, see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
char* get_song_name(const char* song)
```

can invoke undefined behavior because it returns an invalid pointer that points to a local array of the function that will not be alive after exiting the function

```
char str[9999];
//...
char* s = str;
return s;
```

Moreover the function always returns the same pointer (the address of the first element of the local array). So this loop

```
for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
    {
        char *st = fgets(buff, 250, fp);
        st = create_path("c:\\Users\\Marian\\Desktop\\beatles", st);
        name[i] = get_song_name(st); //WORKS HOWEVER CHANGES PRVIOUS INDEXES VALUE TOO
    }`
```

does not make a sense.

You need to allocate dynamically a character array within the function `get_song_name` a pointer to which will be returned from the function.