# Why a member of an array of struct has always the same value?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

So i wanna read a text file and populate an array of structs with the values of the file

this is my file:

```
tile1;1;1;1;0
tile2;0;1;1;1
tile3;1;0;1;1
tile4;1;1;0;1
tile5;1;0;1;0
tile6;0;1;0;1
tile7;1;1;0;0
tile8;0;1;1;0
tile9;0;0;1;1
tileX;1;0;0;1
```

and this is my code

```
FILE *file;

struct tile
{
    char * file_name;
    int l,u,r,d;
};
typedef struct tile tile_t;
tile_t tileData[10];

int main(void)
{
    #define BIG 1000
    char str[BIG];

    if ((file = fopen("res/tiles.conf", "r")) != NULL)
    {
        char* item;
        int i = 0;
        while (fgets(str, BIG, file) != NULL)
        {
            int j = 0;
            for (item = strtok(str, ";"); item != NULL; item = strtok(NULL, ";"))
            {
                //printf("%d item %s\n", j, item);
                switch (j) {
                    case 0: tileData[i].file_name = item;
                        break;
                    case 1: sscanf(item, "%d", &tileData[i].l);
                        break;
                    case 2: sscanf(item, "%d", &tileData[i].u);
                        break;
                    case 3: sscanf(item, "%d", &tileData[i].r);
                        break;
                    case 4: sscanf(item, "%d", &tileData[i].d);
                        break;
                }
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }

        fclose(file);
        
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        {
            printf("index:%d name:%s l:%d u:%d r:%d d:%d\n", k, tileData[k].file_name, tileData[k].l, tileData[k].u, tileData[k].r, tileData[k].d);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the print loop at the end shows me that the int values are correct, while the file name member has always the value of the last row of the file

```
index:0 name:tileX l:1 u:1 r:1 d:0
index:1 name:tileX l:0 u:1 r:1 d:1
index:2 name:tileX l:1 u:0 r:1 d:1
index:3 name:tileX l:1 u:1 r:0 d:1
index:4 name:tileX l:1 u:0 r:1 d:0
index:5 name:tileX l:0 u:1 r:0 d:1
index:6 name:tileX l:1 u:1 r:0 d:0
index:7 name:tileX l:0 u:1 r:1 d:0
index:8 name:tileX l:0 u:0 r:1 d:1
index:9 name:tileX l:1 u:0 r:0 d:1
```

I'm not an experienced C dev but I have done similar programs in the past and this has never happened

Comment: Consider what address does `file_name` point to?  It points to whatever `strtok` returns, which happens to return the relevant part within `str`, the memory for which you reuse on every iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you don't reserve space for the string `filename`, in consequence you write again and again to the same address.

Switch from

```
case 0: tileData[i].file_name = item;
```

to

```
case 0: tileData[i].file_name = strdup(item);
```

Check how to implement `strdup` if it is not available: [Implementation of strdup() in C programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132549/implementation-of-strdup-in-c-programming)

Comment: thanks, that solved it. I guess i must have done something different in the past